# Rethinking arithmetic operations after J.L. Austin's performativity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, kant, computation, analytic-synthetic-divide

According to Kant, arithmetic statements such as "7+5=12" are synthetic a priori. Could we alternatively think of this not as a statement, but as an arithmetic-logic operation to be executed (like a speech-act performed by a machine) and whereas the equal sign "=" becomes the result achieved through this act or maybe the final part of the act, as we would type these numbers into a calculator?

If this is plausible, could we place these operations somewhere in Kant's analytic/synthetic - a priori/a posteriori map (e.g. suggesting that synthetic statements are equivalent to performatives, or alternatively suggesting that they are not a priori, but a posteriori because a machine (mechanical, electrical or biological) must finish the act of computation to achieve the result), or would this require a completely different picture which doesn't fit into Kant's distinctions?

Comment: You don't believe  7 + 5 = 12 unless there's a machine to express it? And the machine may as well be an adding machine from 1950 or a human mathematician since there's really no difference between the two? Am I understanding you correctly? Secondly when I buy groceries and the cash register outputs a paper tape full of numbers, does that represent a "speech act" on the part of the machine?

Comment: ps -- I'm not up on the details of speech acts but wasn't Austin the teacher of Searle? From what I know about Searle he is not someone who would believe that a cash register is the same as a mathematician.

Comment: I would check the truth value of "7+5=12" by computing it. I would either calculate it on a machine or by going through an algorithm in my head. In both cases there is an algorithm to be followed. To me, this appears to be different from simply making a descriptive statement, maybe I am wrong, but I am just wondering if the descriptive/performative distinction can have any use here... That's basically the question...

Comment: You said "I would calculate it on a machine." That's a lot different than a machine calculating it, and humans being a type of machine. That's what you initially said. I'm pushing on the claim that a machine can commit a speech act by itself. And if humans are machines and machines can commit speech acts, is a cash register tape a speech act? We'll get to whether 7 + 5 = 12 or not later.

Comment: Kant used those terms to refer to judgements as opposed to what you are calling an 'operation' (I'm assuming you mean something similar to the informal notion of computation i.e. 'effective method' etc.) but something you should remember is that Kant said that it is a given that somebody knows what the words of the judgements mean before we decide if they're a priori, etc. Its often phrased as "if a proposition is a priori then someone familiar with the language would know it is true just by thinking hard" so you really have to take the familiarity with meaning into account for your analogy.

Comment: I think that you should develop the definition of 'operation' that you are asserting a lot more and explain exactly how you are relating it to Austin's performativity in your mind (you don't mention it explicitly in your question, just the title). What it seems like you are asking is if the computation of an arithmetical statement can be viewed as either analytic/synthetic or apriori/aposteriori because the computation can be viewed analogously to a speech act?

Comment: Thank you for being constructive, Not_Here. With "operations" I meant arithmetic/logic operations, and I was thinking of computer languages where operators can be implemented as functions, so I thought of them as executing an algorithm. And I remember some media theorists mentioning "code as performative language" (one of them could be Alexander Galloway in "Protocol") which made sense to me. I mentioned Austin only to clarify what I meant by performative, but maybe it was superficial.

Comment: + So yes, you are right, this is what I'm asking: To tell the truth value of the arithmetic statement we have to compute it, and that resembles performativity, so can this open up a different way to look at this classic analytic/synthetic distinction?

Comment: @user4894: The 'speech act' would be the process of running the 'program code' (where reading and executing happens at the same time), not the printout of the result. If you ask what the program is, in this case it would be the algorithm to add two integers.

Comment: See [(later) Wittgenstein's phil of math](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-mathematics/#LatWitMatSomPre): arithmetical equations are not statements, with content and truth-values; they are rules.

Comment: You can see Saul Kripke, [Wittgenstein on Rules and Private Language: An Elementary Exposition](https://books.google.it/books?id=N5I3hNIS_yIC&printsec=frontcover), Harvard University Press (1982)

Comment: @ali Question: Do you believe that x + y = y + x for all real numbers? Or only for the computable real numbers, which are a tiny subset of the reals? That is, if x and y are noncomputable real numbers, do you believe that x + y = y + x? No algorithm could possibly calculate their sum.

Comment: @user4894 the example you gave is an algebraic statement which seems to be different from arithmetic statements as it's not a statement about a computation with literal numbers, but about the commutative law. So, in order to find whether it is true or false, we need a proof, rather than a computation with numbers. I guess this proof itself is 'computable' although it is about 'noncomputable numbers'. But I don't know if we should classify "x + y = y + x" as an 'analytic a priori' statement following Kant as opposed to his 'synthetic a priori' statement "7+5=12"... What do you think?

Comment: @ali Fair point. I don't know what Kant says about algebraic statements.

Comment: @user4894 + or could we take both as the same species either after a different interpretation of Kant or simply after Frege and say that they're both analytic? I don't know the answer. The reason I am here is my confusion anyway :)

Comment: @ali Well I don't know anything about Kant, I should probably quit while I'm behind here. I was unclear on your idea that arithmetic truths must be the result of computations. There are a lot of noncomputable real numbers. But they haven't got names so maybe this isn't a problem for Kant. Well some noncomputable numbers have names, for example Chaitin's Omega. Kant didn't have that kind of number in mind I'm sure.